# Fake Open ID provider for testing purposes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, openid

Like SO, I am gonna depend on many Open ID providers to provide user authentication and I will use my own authorization methods. but I'm still in development phase, and don't want to work with real OpenID providers currently, what approach can I use to test my users and their activities in the website (w/o TDD), to emulate real users but not really use Open ID providers.

No need to make auto-transfer of users into real OpenID servers (when moving to production mode) since the current users are just for testing purposes and Unit-test code.

I guess, I need a User Service layer which provides a higly abstracted way to deal with users, so that the move to the real Open ID providers can be smooth in the future and doesn't affect the logic of my already written code.

Using C#.Net 4, ASP.Net MVC 3, Ninject

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) provides both server and client portions of OpenID and can be used to run your own OpenID provider for local testing.

> - Give your site members their own OpenIDs with the provider support included in this library.
> - Sample relying party and provider web sites show you just how to do it.

Comment: In particular, the dotnetopenauth-tools download includes the "OpenIdOfflineProvider" which is perfect for developing/testing RPs.

Answer (score 3):

I simply register my test id as user with various organisations. I don't see anything wrong with that. I get to see the various responses and their differences.

I found it terribly easy to code for openid consumer. Just need to understand the sequence of responses. Draw the UML sequence diagram to aid your understanding before you start coding. No need to fake openId. Otherwise, whip up an openid server yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your services shouldn't depend on OpenID. Just have OpenID plug into an authentication module to provide a local user principal. In development, you can have the auth module return a fake user principal with the permissions you desire.

In a beta environment you could turn on OpenID and use test accounts from any OpenID provider. Having to log in during the development phase will just slow down all the developers. Any authentication bug or internet outage will kill everyone's productivity.

Comment: +1 Good, where to find `auth` module? and does it belong to DotNetOpenAuth?