# Redirect user after successful (fake) login in OpenID Offline Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, openid, offline

Many days ago, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553701/fake-open-id-provider-for-testing-purposes) and I'm set with a working offline OpenID provider (I guess).

What I want is a simple login text box for OpenID identifier which will automatically accept the user and consider the user as logged in, then I want him to be redirected to the main products page (Products => Index).

But, what I didn't know (and didn't find on the internet) is how to go on after the fake authentication process.

I tried to do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string openid)//openid is the identifier taken from the login textbox
{
    var rely = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
    var req = rely.CreateRequest(openid);
    req.RedirectToProvider();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
}
```

First of all, it is not being redirected in the 4th line (instead the login page is refreshed) and second, no authenticated user is really there, I mean when I checked `User` in Watch window, it is not null but Username is empty and there is no authenticated identity which, I guess, means that there is no cookies set.

**P.S:**
1. No exceptions are being thrown. But when I try to call FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLogin() method I get an exception (Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been set).
2. Index action method is marked with [Authorize] attribute, and so when someone tries to browse `Products` it is redirected to the login screen, but when he logs in (fake login), shouldn't he be redirected back to Products page?

I tried this also:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string openid)
{
    var rely = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
    return rely.CreateRequest(openid).RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
}
```

But no luck.

What did I miss? and how to make it work as expected? I can depend on myself but I need a decent documentation for OpenID especially for the offline local provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example: [OpenID and OAuth using DotNetOpenAuth in ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/08/openid-and-oauth-using-dotnetopenauth-in-asp-net-mvc/)

```
public ActionResult OpenId(string openIdUrl)
{
    var response = Openid.GetResponse();
    if (response == null)
    {
        // User submitting Identifier
        Identifier id;
        if (Identifier.TryParse(openIdUrl, out id))
        {
            try
            {
                var request = Openid.CreateRequest(openIdUrl);
                var fetch = new FetchRequest();
                fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
                fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First);
                fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);
                request.AddExtension(fetch);
                return request.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
            }
            catch (ProtocolException ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("OpenID Exception...", ex);
                return RedirectToAction("LoginAction");
            }
        }
        _logger.Info("OpenID Error...invalid url. url='" + openIdUrl + "'");
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    // OpenID Provider sending assertion response
    switch (response.Status)
    {
        case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
            var fetch = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
            string firstName = "unknown";
            string lastName = "unknown";
            string email = "unknown";
            if(fetch!=null)
            {
                firstName = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First);
                lastName = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);
                email = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
            }
            // Authentication       
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName: email, createPersistentCookie: false);
            // Redirection
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
        case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
            _logger.Info("OpenID: Cancelled at provider.");
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
            _logger.Error("OpenID Exception...", response.Exception);
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Basically, your action method is called twice:

The first time by your form being submitted by the user.

The second time is a call back (redirect) from the OpenID provider. 
This time, there will be a value for the `response`. If `response.Status` is valid, you can log your user in using the [`FormsAuthentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx) class and finally you can redirect him to your main products page.

Comment: +1 thanks, I'll try it and I have a feeling this code works for both local and real OpenID server right?

Comment: I haven't tested it with the *OpenIdOfflineProvider*, but i it should work on both of them.

Comment: It gets called once, `response` then is `null`, and then the callback from my OpenID provider is being called as a `GET` request and the code under `// OpenID Provider sending assertion response` is never get reached. I'll Edit my question to put the 2 `Login` action methods I have.